# Разница в порядке ключевых слов в объявлении с++

Tags: c++, функции, объявление

Объясните мне пожалуйста в каком порядке можно ставить ключевые слова в объявлении. Допустим у нас есть объявление inline-функции:

```
inline int Sum(int a, int b)
{ return a+b; }
```

Но мы можем поменять местами int и inline:

```
int inline Sum(int a, int b)
{ return a+b; }
```

И тогда ничего не поменяется, что лично для меня очень странно ведь функция объявляется, как

```
имя-типа идентификатор {тело-функции}
```

А тут идет как будто функция возвращает не int, а inline(очень грубо сказано, но так это выглядит в моём понимании). Так вот, это ещё не всё. Если мы попробуем такую же схему провернуть с шаблоном функции, то у нас уже так не получится и запись по типу:

```
int template<type T> Sum(T a, T b)
{ return a+b; }
//функция приведена для примера, в реальности такая функция была бы скорее всего бесполезна
```

Уже не пройдёт. И так же с объявлением переменных, почему-то запись по типу:

```
int const a;
```

Спокойно скомпилируется, что вызывает у меня аналогичные вопросы, как и с функцией. Есть ли какие-то специальные правила, для разрешения данного вопроса или что-то подобное?
Заранее благодарю за помощь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ такой же, как и в прошлый раз - читайте грамматику. :)

Всякие `int`, `const`, `inline` - это все части т.н. [*decl-specifier-seq*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.general). Внутри него порядок не важен.

Всякие `*`, `&`, `(...)`, `[...]` - не его часть (это части [declarator](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator)-а, вместе с именем функции/переменной).

`template <...>` - тоже не его часть. Как вы заметили, он всегда левее decl-specifier-seq.

Например, в `const int *a, b;`, decl-specifier-seq - это `const int`, и он относится к обоим переменным. А `*a` и `b` - это деклараторы, так что звездочка действует только на свою переменную.